# Error:Could not initialize class com.android.tools.idea.gradle.eclipse.GradleImport

Tags: android, gradle, import

I have just updated android studio 2.3 to 3.0.1 and the next error occurs: 
**Error:Could not initialize class com.android.tools.idea.gradle.eclipse.GradleImportCould not initialize class com.android.tools.idea.gradle.eclipse.GradleImport**
I'm working on windows and gradle 3.3
I try to clean, make project, invalidate cache/restart but it does not work
I try this command:
     *`gradlew clean` and `gradlew -stop` but it throw:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3.0-all.zip
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Please how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error after updating to Android Studio 3.0.1 and what worked for me in the end was to update the following in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
}
```

I also needed to add `jcenter()` under `repositories` in the same file after that.

I then also needed to update `buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'`to `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'` in the `build.gradle` file of the app.

After those steps my app compiled and started fine.